# How to write a regex for this for this URL type?

Tags: regex, url

I have question regarding regular expressions. Given example URL below:

```
example.com/2012/12/4/akfjalj.html
```

How do I write or define a regex for this type of URL?

It would be a great help if you can provide me with it.

Comment: please show some more variations, it is unclear to me which part of your url is variable and what you want to do. just testing if an url matches? replacing parts?

Comment: `example.com\/2012\/12\/4\/akfjalj\.html` should match.

Comment: Anyone writing a regex needs to know what parts of the URL will be constant and what parts of the URL will change (in order to cover the pattern of the changing parts with a regex).

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$url = "http://example.com/2012/3/1/test.html";
$pattern = '/^https?:\/\/[a-z]+\/[0-9]{4}\/[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{1,2}\/[a-z]+\.html$/';
$ismatch = preg_match($pattern, $url);
echo $ismatch; // 1 if true, 0 if false
?>
```

referenced http://www.regular-expressions.info/php.html

Comment: Thank you for providing the Regex @kitgui.com

And I'm sorry for not making it clear

I want to detect whether the website is Blog or a Forum, as far as i know the URL structure for blog has a certain pattern, example: http://www.example.com/2012/04/abc.html, manually i can tell it is a blog by checking certain strings in URL - "/2012/04/"

I want to do it programmaticaly in PHP SCRIPT which can automatically detect URL's having YEAR & MONTH in URL, so that i can define it as a BLOG.

So for this one i want to write a REGEX..,

let me know if it is not understandable.

Thanks in advance,